# Options for Linux OS executable archive files - self installers

Tags: linux, unix, installation

I am looking to create a web-project that is able to install with a program.  The user should be able to download an archive file or tar file, run it (executable), and the setup script would ask for paths and configurable values and then unpack its 'payload' and sorting out the contents for deployment.

This would be a Linux version of the MSI installer.  Is there such a thing for Linux operating systems?  This does not involve kernel level manipulations.  All it needs to do is copy directories and files on the filesystem, which should cover about 80% if not more of all the *nix distributions.

**EDIT - I should mention also that this does not have to have a graphical UI - in fact it would be best if this whole process ran from the shell only.**

What about BIN files?  Also is it possible to simply 'shove' a tar file into an executable script?

Comment: there was also a converter from tar to BIN

Comment: Do you need control over where the files are copied to? For example 0install.net won't let your installer choose where the files go, but it will tell you where it put them. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Yes that might work - this is a website - 0install.net?  I will check it out, thank you for the reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shar` archives are self-extracting in most unixes (written in `sh`). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar

Comment: I had read your comment first.  Thank you this just might be it ;0)

Comment: @Matt1776, the question about installer-creating software for linux is still open. A week ago I have seen some installer in linux-related news (opennet.ru or linux.org.ru) and I want to find that news post.

Comment: ya magu govorit pa ruski ochen nimnoshka, but not enough to read a page in russian :)  That is interesting - if you can send me this info in english I would love to read it, thank you!  matthewrishii@gmail.com

Comment: @Matt1776, there is a translate.google.com, it will help in reading texts, written in various languages. But I still can't find that news posting.

Comment: @Matt1776, may be here http://www.linux.org.ru/news/opensource/3665527 (Freearc, ... Создание самораспаковывающихся (SFX) архивов и инсталяторов = Creating of self-extracting (SFX) archives and installers). http://freearc.org/

Answer (score 2):

Software "installers" for Linux are typically distributed as "packages."  This can vary from distribution to distribution, but Debian or Debian-based distributions (like Ubuntu) typically use `.deb` packages, Redhat and Fedora use `.rpm` packages (along with some other distributions).

I can't say much for any distribution but Ubuntu with the `.deb` packages, but these operate a lot like one would expect an installer to.  However, they do not typically allow one to select installation directories - they just put it in a standard location.  See http://www.debian.org/doc/FAQ/ch-pkg_basics.en.html for more information on Debian packages or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager for more information on RPM.

Comment: To clarify "work like...an installer": for example, in Ubuntu, when you double-click a .deb package, a package installer program opens it - it shows information about the package (e.g. the description contained in the package), and has an "Install package" button.

Answer (score 0):

There are some, e.g. InstallJammer http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/60380 or  AutoPackage http://www.autopackage.org/

Comment: Both of these solutions seem very focused on a graphical UI solution and also appear to be pretty involved and complicated.  Are there any simple solutions that focus more on a command line utility?

Comment: @Matt1776, I need to check some commercial programs for linux and their packaging. sometimes smth like you want is used.

Do you want program to install with package manager (to register itself in deb or rpm database) or just to unpack and run?

Comment: Unpack and Run .. It would also be nice to be able to ask the user questions about where to put the software.

Comment: There is a `shar` ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar ). It will create self-extracting archives, written in shell (`bash`)

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you - may not solve all my problems but this is very cool and much closer to what I was looking for :0)

Comment: @matt1776 InstallBuilder (http://installbuilder.bitrock.com) offers self-contained binaries as well as registration with RPM And DEB

Answer (score 0):

Check out [autopackage](http://autopackage.org). Basically a user just has to download the .package file, which contains everything, make it executable, and then run it. It can be installed from the command line if desired but there is also a GUI option if the user double clicks from the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

FreeArc from http://freearc.org/ claims to create SFX archives and installers.

Comment: @osgx - thank you for these suggestions, I will investigate this one as well :0)